# How to upload and complile opensource project in any IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ide, clang, clion

Has this project https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core.git. It needed clang.

I make some changes and now need to debug it. When I tried to open as project, make and debug in Clion, Kdevelop, QtCreator, process stop with many different errors. Can't initial path of included files and depends.

P.S. sorry for my bad English:(

Comment: Can you give examples of the errors you get? Is it that you need to debug it in a debugger and it shows assembly code and not your C++ code? Or is it a problem with making it build in the IDE?

Comment: Problem with importing all source files into project.
Error like this:
error: #error Do not compile Asio library source with ASIO_HEADER_ONLY defined
 # error Do not compile Asio library source with ASIO_HEADER_ONLY defined
When I do ./autogen.sh, ./configure && make in console - completely